# MS Access Management Studio

Tags: ms-access

At SQL Server, we know SQL Server Management Studio.
At MySQL, we know HeidiSQL, PHPMyAdmin, etc..
I am looking for MS Access client (management studio) is there unofficial tool which I can use to manage Queries?

MS access built in tools can not run multiple Queries like SQL Server Management Studio.

Please help

Comment: Well, the answer is: Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 2):

**There is nothing like MS Access Management Studio**. As far as I know you cannot execute multiple statements in MS Access. The best I can think of is that you can string together your multiple queries using VBA and then execute it. Also note that you cannot perform multiple SQL statement within single operation using the the ACE/Jet engine as it does not support it.

Also check [WinSql](http://web.synametrics.com/WinSQL.htm)

Comment: Win Sql cannot execute multiple statements against access.

Comment: Also - ACE/Jet certainly does handle mutiple statement atomicity.  I use the JDBC/ODBC bridge from Matlab to hit Access, and I can open transactions, execute multiple statements and commit.  I have even interrupted the transaction, and rolled back.